# Selecting a default select option through the setValue() method with angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using reactive forms for my form template. I have my `setValue()` in my subscribe method so I can set the form controls for my product to my subscribed to data. The problem I am having Is that I want my select options in my html to select the correct value. Right now it's not selecting any value  it just displays a blank select box. I know the value that I am setting with my `setValue()` method  the category and supplier I set it to is correct. I know that values in my html select option is not equal to what I am setting them to and that is why they won't select in the html. How do I set them "===" so that it will automatically select the correct value based on my `setValue()` method. I have declared my form and have click method that calls the `selectedId()`.

In my ts file I have all my services declared. In this function I am getting my product data by id then setting my form control instances to those values.

```
export class UpdateProductComponent implements OnInit {
  availability:boolean;
  category:number;
  orderBy: String;
  Ascdesc: String;
  page = 0;
  home: Home[];
  product: Product;
  categories: Category[];
  suppliers: Supplier[];
  selectedCategory: Category;
  id: number;



selectedId(id){

this.id = id;

this.homeService.getProduct(this.id).subscribe(data => {
  this.product = data;
  this.updateProduct.setValue({
    id: this.product.id,
    productName: this.product.productName,
    category:this.product.category,
    fullPrice: this.product.fullPrice,
    salePrice: this.product.salePrice,
    availability: this.product.availability,
    supplier:this.product.supplier,
    discount: this.product.discount
  });

}); 

}
// not important to my problem 
selectedId2(id){
  this.id = id ;

  this.homeService.getProduct(this.id).subscribe(data => {
    this.product = data;
  }); 
}


  selectCategory (category) {
       this.category = category.category;
   }

   available(boolean){

    this.availability = boolean;
    }

    update($event){
      this.homeService.getByParm(this.availability,this.category).subscribe(data => {
        this.home = data;
      }); 

    }

// Where my form is declared and form controls  are assigned
    updateProduct = new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(''),
      productName: new FormControl(''),
      category: new FormControl(null),
      fullPrice: new FormControl(''),
      salePrice: new FormControl(''),
      availability: new FormControl(''),
      supplier: new FormControl(null),
      discount: new FormControl(''),

    });

constructor(private homeService: HomeService,private supplierService: SupplierService, private categoryService: CategoryService) { }


SortPrice($event:any){
  let icon = document.getElementById("asc-desc1");
  if(icon.className === "fas fa-angle-down"){
    icon.className ="fas fa-angle-up";
    this.homeService.getByPriceAsc().subscribe(data => {
    this.home = data;
  });
  }else{
    icon.className ="fas fa-angle-down"
    this.homeService.getByPriceDesc().subscribe(data => {
      this.home = data;
    });
  };

}

//submit method form my form 
onSubmit() {
  this.homeService.updateProduct(this.updateProduct.value).subscribe((res)=>{
    console.log("Created a product")
  });

  console.warn(this.updateProduct.value);
}


SortSale($event:any){
  let icon = document.getElementById("asc-desc2");
  if(icon.className === "fas fa-angle-down"){
    icon.className ="fas fa-angle-up";
    this.homeService.getBySaleAsc().subscribe(data => {
    this.home = data;
  });
  }else{
    icon.className ="fas fa-angle-down"
    this.homeService.getBySaleDesc().subscribe(data => {
      this.home = data;
    });
  };

}
SortDiscount($event:any){
  let icon = document.getElementById("asc-desc3");
  if(icon.className === "fas fa-angle-down"){
    icon.className ="fas fa-angle-up";
    this.homeService.getByDiscountAsc().subscribe(data => {
    this.home = data;
  });
  }else{
    icon.className ="fas fa-angle-down"
    this.homeService.getByDiscountDesc().subscribe(data => {
      this.home = data;
    });
  };

}


ngOnInit() {




  this.supplierService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
    this.suppliers = data;
  });

    this.homeService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
    this.home = data;
  });




  this.categoryService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
    this.categories = data;
  });

}

}
```

this is my html

```
<td><input class="form-control"  formControlName="id"  disabled></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" id="productName"  formControlName="productName" ></td>
          <td >
              <select class="form-control" formControlName="category">
                <option [ngValue]="this.product.category.categoryName">{{this.product.category.categoryName}} </option>
                <option *ngFor="let category of categories" [ngValue]= "category">{{category.categoryName}}</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          <td><input class="form-control" id="fullprice" formControlName="fullPrice"></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" id="saleprice"   formControlName="salePrice"></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="availability"  formControlName="availability" ></td>
          <td>
            <select class="form-control" formControlName="supplier" >

              <option *ngFor="let supplier of suppliers" [ngValue]="supplier">{{supplier.supplierName}}</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input class="form-control" formControlName="discount" id="discount" ></td>
```

Comment: What does `this.updateProduct.setValue` do? That's not the reference to your form control, you're not referencing the select list in that line of code, that's why it's not updating. Or is that the reference to your form? Show all of your component code please.

Comment: What is `categories`  in your HTML? Is it list of object or category name?

Comment: @Train it's reference to my form not to my select list my select list options is being populated through the `*ngfor` for my category and supplier.

Comment: @ppgowda4   it's a list of objects  but I am displaying the the name through the object or accessing the name in the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `updateProduct` is a formGroup and service data is dynamically loaded based on ID and form group has default values then use `this.updateProduct.patchValue({...});`. This will update the form group with available values. You can set it partially also with selected fields.

If you want to set all values then `setValue({...})` should do the job.

In HTML, `[value]` attribute is sufficient to set the value. Update your first option to set `category` as value instead of name.
Make sure `category` type in formGroup is same as category object.

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="category">
     <option [value]="this.product.category"> {{this.product.category.categoryName}} </option>
     <option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category">{{category.categoryName}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Could you create a function that selects the category that matches this.product.category  option that then selects that option from the list of categories. I was thinking I could do that but I don not know how to approach that.